# Behavior when async: false and true

Tags: requirejs, dojo, amd, dijit.form

I am using AMD way of coding and when I make async:false I don't see any difference in execution behavior i.e. making async true or false I see no difference.

Please have a look at code snippet below:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true, parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
require(["dojo/domReady!"], function(){
alert("I am inside DOM ready");
});

require(["dojo/ready"], function(ready){
    ready(function(){
    alert("I am inside ready");
  });
});
</script>
<body>
some div's here
</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT:
In both the case i see first "I am inside DOM ready" and then "I am inside ready" alert next.

Could you please explain what is the difference if I add async : true and async:false?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, if `async` is set to a truthy value (`true`, `1`, etc.), `dojo/domReady` and `dojo/ready` will be loaded when `require` is called. If `async` is not set, these modules are loaded immediately when `dojo.js` is loaded. So there is no impact on how *your* code executes, it’s just about when those modules become available for use.

This is snippet from Dojo AMD description:

> For backwards-compatibility, the loader starts up in synchronous mode by default, which loads the Dojo base API automatically:
>
> ```html
> <script src="path/to/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
> <script>
>   // the dojo base API is available here
> </script>
> ```
>
> To put the loader in the AMD mode, set the async configuration variable to truthy:
>
> ```html
> <script data-dojo-config="async: 1" src="path/to/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
> <script>
>   // ATTENTION: nothing but the AMD API is available here
> </script>
> ```

Note that you can only set the async flag before dojo.js is loaded, and that in AMD mode, neither Dojo Base nor any other library is automatically loaded - it is entirely up to the application to decide which modules/libraries to load.